# Capitalizing Lower-Case Letters

Tags: php, html, css

For the code below, how could I make `$row["title"]` and `$row["displayurl"]` display in capital letters even if they contain lower-case letters?

```
echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'" TARGET="_blank">'.$row["title"].'</a>  <div class="dispurl">'.$row["displayurl"].'</div></td>';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`strtoupper()`](http://www.php.net/strtoupper)

```
'.strtoupper($row["title"]).'
```

Reference: [PHP manual on string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php)

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what you mean by "Capitalizing"

```
strtoupper("lowercase srting"); // => LOWERCASE STRING
ucfirst("lowercase string"); // => Lowercase string
ucwords("lowercase string"); // => Lowercase String
```

It could be that this won't work with unicode Strings, but this works with unicode strings to:

```
mb_convert_case("lowercase string", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
// => Lowercase String
// be aware:
mb_convert_case("UPPERCASE STRING", MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
// => Uppercase String

mb_convert_case("lowercase string", MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
// => LOWERCASE STRING
```

There is no direct approach for `ucfirst` with multibyte characters. [PHP-Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php)

You can also do this in css:

```
td.sitename1 a, td.sitename1 div {
  text-transform: uppercase;
} /* Will make 'UPPERCASE STRING' */

td.sitename1 a, td.sitename1 div {
  text-transform: capitalize;
} /* Will make 'Capitalized String' */
```

Comment: `MB_CASE_TITLE` is not directly analog to `ucwords` because it will lowercase the characters that are not the first ones in the words, while `ucwords` won't.

Answer (score 3):

in CSS:

```
text-transform: uppercase
```

in PHP:

```
string strtoupper ( string $string )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, use [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/mb_strtoupper) if you're using anything other than ASCII characters.

`strtoupper` is locale-dependent, and as such may have differernt results in different machines. In fact, it can even have different results for ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

See [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php), making your line look like:

```
echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'" TARGET="_blank">'.strtoupper($row["title"]).'</a>  <div class="dispurl">'.strtoupper($row["displayurl"]).'</div></td>';
```